# Pandas read_excel interference between na_values and converters bug?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have found some strange behavior when using the Pandas read_excel function.  I have a contrived example of a spreadsheet that looks like:

```
Name    age weight
Bob     35   70
Alice   15   ...
Sam     ...  65
Susan   92   63
Harold  42   ...
```

Missing values are indicated by '...' and I would like them read as NaN.  I would also like to convert the weights to grams.  My first attempt was:

```
df=pd.read_excel('test.xls',na_values='...',converters={'weight':lambda y:y*1000})
```

Unfortunately, this applies the converter function first, so that Susan and Harold's missing weights become not three dots but 3000 dots, which does not match the given "na_value" entry and are thus not turned into NaN.  This is highly unexpected.

Is there a reason this is the best behavior for this function?

Did I do something obviously wrong in my implementation of it?

What's the best way to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `converters` are run before `na_values` are applied, which is why you're seeing this behavior.
Just add a condition in your converter to catch the `...` instances in `weights` -
 like adding a hand-rolled `na_values`:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xls", 
                   na_values="...", 
                   converters={"weight":lambda w: w*1000 if isinstance(w, int) else None})

print(df)

     Name   age   weight
0     Bob  35.0  70000.0
1   Alice  15.0      NaN
2     Sam   NaN  65000.0
3   Susan  92.0  63000.0
4  Harold  42.0      NaN
```

Keep the actual `na_values` argument to ensure `...` values in the `age` field are also converted.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I would tweak your solution just a bit:  `converters={"weight":lambda w: w*1000 if isinstance(w, int) else x})' will cause the convereter to leave a non int value _alone_, which I think is better.  Ultimately, I abandoned this approach due to other weird behavior.  It's difficult to give a simple example, but in my actual data, using a lambda function like this changes the dtype of the resulting column, and breaks some Numpy functionality.  A later call to DataFrame.corr() will ignore a column that has been subjected to a lambda for some reason.  Odd.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', na_values='...') \
       .eval("weight = weight * 1000", inplace=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use the converters argument in this case.
Make that operation after the read_excel. 
I even believe that has better performance.

Like this:

```
df=pd.read_excel('test.xls', ....
df['weight'] *= 1000
```